# Send ajax request to Netty HTTP server

Tags: java, javascript, html, asynchronous, netty

I try send async request from JavaScript to Netty 4 HTTP server and don't get response.
Here is code what i use.

Netty server initialization:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
try {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new HttpHelloWorldServerInitializer());

    Channel ch = b.bind(port).sync().channel();
    ch.closeFuture().sync();
} finally {
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

Pipeline initialization - HttpHelloWorldServerInitializer

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
p.addLast("decoder", new HttpServerCodec());
p.addLast("handler", new HttpHelloWorldServerHandlerIn());
```

Handler - HttpHelloWorldServerHandlerIn

```
public class HttpHelloWorldServerHandlerIn extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    private static final byte[] CONTENT = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' };

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK,
                    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT));
            response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
            response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
            ctx.write(response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Netty test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status + " " + xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8081/test", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Text here</h2></div>
<div id="myDiv2"><h2></h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In HTML page i see xmlhttp.readyState=4, xmlhttp.status=0, xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders() is empty.

Netty log show correct dump what i send to JavaScript

```
2013 4:15:19 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler logMessage
INFO: [id: 0x619b60f9, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59641 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081] WRITE(100B)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
|00000010| 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74 |.Content-Type: t|
|00000020| 65 78 74 2f 70 6c 61 69 6e 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 |ext/plain..Conte|
|00000030| 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 31 31 0d 0a 43 |nt-Length: 11..C|
|00000040| 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d |onnection: keep-|
|00000050| 61 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a 0d 0a 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 |alive....Hello W|
|00000060| 6f 72 6c 64                                     |orld            |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

and

```
2013 4:15:19 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler flush
INFO: [id: 0x619b60f9, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59641 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081] FLUSH
```

Please help! What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would check with wireshark to see if the bytes are really send over the write. Also you should check if the ChannelFuture returned by write(...) was failed for some reason.

Something like:

```
ChannelFuture future = ctx.write(...);
future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        System.out.println("success=" future.isSuccess());
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            future.cause().printStracktrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And wireshark show all bytes that i send. But browser don't show response

Comment: This means it was send over the wire.. Maybe debuggin in the browser helps

Answer (score 0):

Answer was very simple...
Just add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to response header:

```
response.headers().set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
```